# Software center does not open

Tags: software-center

I have a problem with Software Center. It doesn't open and I could not install any software on my 32bit- Ubuntu.

This happened after I have tried to upgrade the System.

Comment: Open a terminal by pressing `ctrl`+`alt`+`t` and run `sudo apt-get install --reinstall software-center`.

Comment: also run the command `software-center` in an open terminal so that you can see where it gets all hung up. Please post the output for when the application gets stuck.

Comment: kevin@Keivan-PC:~$ software-center
2015-05-13 02:15:42,060 - softwarecenter.ui.gtk3.app - INFO - setting up proxy 'None'

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/software-center", line 130, in <module>
    app = SoftwareCenterAppGtk3(options, args)
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/app.py", line 291, in __init__

Comment: self.cache = get_pkg_info()
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/db/pkginfo.py", line 245, in get_pkg_info
    from softwarecenter.db.pkginfo_impl.aptcache import AptCache
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/db/pkginfo_impl/aptcache.py", line 30, in <module>
    from aptdaemon.client import AptClient
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/aptdaemon/client.py", line 43, in <module>
    _GObject = GObject.GObject

Comment: File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gi/__init__.py", line 62, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(_static_binding_error)
AttributeError: When using gi.repository you must not import static modules like "gobject". Please change all occurrences of "import gobject" to "from gi.repository import GObject". See: https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=709183

Comment: Those are listed after I typed the command Software-center

Comment: @Keivan Please edit your question and list down the output of the command `software-center`

Comment: 2015-05-13 09:41:48,364 - softwarecenter.ui.gtk3.app - INFO - setting up proxy 'None'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/software-center", line 130, in <module>
    app = SoftwareCenterAppGtk3(options, args)
File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/app.py", line 291, in __init__
    self.cache = get_pkg_info()
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/db/pkginfo.py", line 245, in get_pkg_info
    from softwarecenter.db.pkginfo_impl.aptcache import AptCache